# dynamically change the size of an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I have an array defined as;

> static double Temp_data[TABLE_SIZE];

I want to change the size of the array according to the user input.
Is this possible?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You probably want to use `std::vector<double> Temp_data;`

Then you can use its `resize()` member function to set the size as you see fit.

Edit: just to be clear, you generally want to avoid using `new` directly if you can (and in this case, you can very easily). Direct use of `new` is a constant source of bugs of quite a few types. `std::vector` handles quite a few corner cases that are difficult to get correct with `new`, ensures that the data gets cleaned up when it goes out of scope, etc.

I've said before, and I'll repeat here: at one time, you had little choice but to write code that used `new`. Now, you do have a choice -- and you should exercise it. Given a modern compiler and standard library, there's almost never any reason to allocate an array with `new`.

Comment: But why do you have to specify size in vector?

Comment: @Rohit: You don't. You can just start with an empty `vector` and use `push_back` to add as many items as you want (well, up to a limit, of course). If, however, the user is supplying a size, you can use `resize` to make it that size.

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin. But I want to use either CArray or Arrays.

Comment: @Rohit 1. You may want to access the ith element, to do that, you need to resize the vector first. 2. For efficiency concern. If you know the size of the array, you can resize it, better than keep pushing back. (In this case, `reserve()` maybe a better choice though.)

Comment: @gishu: CArray? You mean the MFC one, or something else? Why? I use `std::vector` in MFC programs without any problem at all. Anyway, given those choices, use CArray. It's not as clean as `std::vector`, but still a lot better than using `new` directly.

Comment: Yeah, I meant CArray. I also think vector is much more convenient. But there is a function that only accept CArrays or arrays in my project. Thats why I have to use one of them. Thanks.

Comment: @gishu: You can use a `std::vector` with a function that requires an array -- when you need to call that function, just give it `&myvector[0]`, or (with a newer compiler) `myvector.data()`.

Comment: You have `reserve` and `resize`but they aren't really specifying the array size in vector. you can just keep on using vector with out any concern of the size. `reserve` and `resize`are for efficiency concerns.

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin. I can't use myvector.data(). I used &myvector[0] and it is working fine. Btw How do I access all the elements in the vector?

Comment: @gishu: the usual ways are by index or iterator. I have a feeling I may not understand what you're asking though...

Comment: I was asking that, because I need to pass the whole array once. Anyway I will check it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @gishu: you don't normally pass an entire array -- you pass a pointer to the beginning (typically along with something to tell how large it is). In fact, that's the only way to pass a normal array. When you try to specify a parameter of the type "array of X", the compiler will adjust it to "pointer to X".

Comment: @Rohit So you can do `std::vector<int> a; a[10] = 10;` without using `resize`?

Comment: 7 is the magic number used in most cases. So for an empty vector there will be memory allocated only until 7 or what ever magic number the algorithm follows

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic memory allocation.

```
int size;
cin>>size
int *ptr = new int[size];
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: You have more control on array than vector

Comment: Why do you say, You have more control on an array than a vector?

Comment: Sometimes, a vector is overkill. A vector does do everything an array does, but lets you add new elements beyond its current size, resize it, search through it, erase elements, etc

Comment: @Rohit: So far, it sounds like you think a `vector` is the one that really gives you more control. In any case, it's at least partly true -- if you really need something that doesn't resize (for example), consider `std::array` instead. Searching (for one example) isn't part of `vector` though -- you'd use a standard algorithm, which an apply just as well to an array.

Comment: And i think you prefer using `array` for performance reasons too.

Comment: well in a debug build vectors can be slow, but in a release build the difference is almost nothing between vectors and arrays.

Answer (score 2):

T *pData

pData = new T[NUM_ELEMENTS];

Basically using the new operator. Read more about new from any C++ reference